# Unable to import 'selenium' : pylint(import-error)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, pip

I created a virtual environment and tried to import selenium inside one of the python files I have inside that venv and it's throwing me this error.

Both my python3 and pip3 have the same source.

I tried `pip3 install selenium` and `python3 -m pip install -U selenium`, both didn't work.

I can import the selenium package from the command line without any problem. Will this be any problem with my text editor? I'm using vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My python interpreter inside vscode was pointing to another version of python. I changed that to pyton3 and it worked. To change the python3 interpreter, open command palette(ctrl+shift+p) and search for,
*Python : Select Interpreter*. Now change that to the correct path and you're good to go.